# Save IPython print output into file

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to access and save the text output from an IPython cell, such as output produced by the print command. Note that this is different from _.

E.g. if execute this cell:

```
def printer():
    print 'boom'

print 'zoom'
printer()
```

The output is:

```
zoom
boom
```

And `_` returns an empty string.
I would like to somehow access the buffer that was put to the screen (`Out` cell). Thanks

Comment: If you want a general Python solution, you can always reassign `sys.stdout` to something that tees the output to both the real `stdout` and to something else (like a trivial thing that just remembers the last thing written).

Answer (score 0):

For a general Python solution, you can redirect `sys.stdout` to something that passes the output through to the real thing, but also keeps track of what you printed.

The big problem with this is that there's no way to tell which `stdout.write`s came from a given `print` statement. A `print` could call `write` multiple times. One option is to just remember the last *line*.

Here's a quick&dirty hack (in a real program, you'd want to forward everything else to the real `stdout`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

class CachingStdOut(object):
    def __init__(self, stdout):
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.last = ''
    def write(self, stuff):
        self.last = (self.last + stuff).splitlines()[-1]
        return self.stdout.write(stuff)

sys.stdout = CachingStdOut(sys.stdout)

def printer():
    print 'boom'

print 'zoom'
zoom = sys.stdout.last # the last line printed was 'zoom\n'
printer()

print zoom
```

---

Python 3 makes this easier by having a `print` function that you can just hide with your own, instead of a `print` statement that you can't. If you're willing to switch to Python 3 style, while still staying in 2.7, you can `from __future__ import print_function`. Of course you have to decide what "the last thing printed" means, when it may well be a bunch of separate arguments and keyword arguments, but whatever you decide you can do easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys

_print = print
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    global last_print
    last_print = args, kwargs
    _print(*args, **kwargs)

def printer():
    print('boom')

print('zoom')
zoom, _ = last_print # zoom now holds ('zoom'), and _ holds {}
printer()

print(*zoom)
```

Comment: Actually it wouldn't be necessary to distinguish between the different print statements, I just the need the entire printed buffer. This is not bad for a workaround, but I would prefer not to overwrite `stdout` : )

Comment: @csaladenes: But I suspect "the entire printed buffer" is often going to be just the final `'\n'` or `' '`, because there's nothing that guarantees that a `print` does exactly one `write`. Of course you can test that and see if I'm right in practice…

Comment: @csaladenes: Meanwhile, unless IPython has some built-in magic for this that I don't know about (which it might, so definitely wait for someone else to chime in!), the only options are the ones given in this answer, or IPython-specific stuff that will be even hairier (e.g., capturing the data between the interpreter and the cell).